# Google Apps not autocompleted in application finder in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I like to start all my favourite applications via application finder (xfce4-appfinder), normally called via +. But if I wrote e.g. "gmail" appfinder doesn't find it if I hit . Here i have to hit ,  and .

Is there an easy way to let appfinder find the google apps too?

If i start xfce4-appfinder i can wrote "gmail" and hit  because the application list is already opened.

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is that there's no desktop app for the gmail platform, so the application finder has no way to locate an unexisting file. What we can do to troubleshoot the problem is creating a desktop launcher that points to an executable file (actually called script) that contains the command to open your default browser with the link to the gmail web. Let's do this:

You may find this link interesting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles [describes the process i'll explain][1]

1- open your text editor of choice and paste the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash

x-www-browser gmail.com
```

2- save the document on your desktop

3-  open a new file in your text editor of choice and paste

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=gmail
Comment=this opens the gmail.com domain
Exec=[write the absolute path of the first file here]
Icon=[ write here the absolute path of the icon]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

4- You can download the Gmail icon and paste the absolute path of the file on the Icon section

5- Remember to save the files on your desktop
Gmail

6- Now we have to give the files permission to be executable

7- right click on the document and go to properties

8- go to permissions and click in the allow this file to run as a program

9- now you can type the gmail command on your application finder or click on the desktop icon

10- if you prefer a minimalist desktop you can move the files to any other place, it just made easier the whole process, it's just personal preference

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to create only one file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=gmail
Comment=this opens the gmail.com domain
Exec=x-www-browser gmail.com
Icon=[ write here the absolute path of the icon]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;Network;
```

and save it to `/home/YOUUSER/local/share/applications/`